# Changing Display Path to /civicrm on frontend

Tags: wordpress

I have just done a new install of CiviCRM 5.15.1 on Wordpress 5.2.2, and before going any further, is it possible to change the mydomain.com/civicrm path to civi pages to something else? Say, mydomain.com/members.

Or will this muck everything up for future updates?

Thanks for your advice.

Cheers,
Tracy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to CiviCRM Stackexchange. Ofcourse you change the path to point to your own alias.

You will need to create a blank page in wordpress with member url or update the url alias of default CiviCRM page.

Make sure you use the same alias to define 'WordPress Base Page' in CiviCRM CMS integration(CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> CMS Database Integration)

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep. Just to clarify, there is already the default CiviCRM page created. Can I change the name of that to 'Members' and then change the Wordpress Base Page? Or does it have to be a completely new page. Also, Would I need to change the Resource URLs under System Settings, or are they okay at mydomain/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm

Comment: Yes, you can change the default CiviCRM page title and url but you need to update the new url  in Wordpress Base Page. No need to change anything in resource url